# Assimp сборка под MinGW

Tags: c++, opengl, g++

Как собрать [Офсайт_Assimp](http://www.assimp.org/) [[Код_на_Github]](https://github.com/assimp/assimp) под MinGW в статическую библиотеку?

При сборке используя аргументы cmak'a (cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles")  и компиляции получаю ошибки "платформенного кода"..

```
    inline int ASSIMP_stricmp(const char *s1, const char *s2)
{
    ai_assert(NULL != s1 && NULL != s2);

#if (defined _MSC_VER)

    return ::_stricmp(s1,s2);
#elif defined( __GNUC__ )

    return ::strcasecmp(s1,s2);//У MinGW нет этого метода ...
#else

    char c1, c2;
    do  {
        c1 = tolower(*s1++);
        c2 = tolower(*s2++);
    }
    while ( c1 && (c1 == c2) );
    return c1 - c2;
#endif
}
```

P.S. Используется Windows

Comment: что? ошибки "платформенного кода"? что?

Comment: Ввёл некоторую ясность что я имел ввиду под  "платформенного кода"

Comment: google://stricmp

Comment: Фишка в том что это одно из проблем и так просто она не решается пробовал собирать используя советы отсюда но нечего толкового не вышло http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39659331/strncasecmp-and-strcasecmp-has-not-been-declared

Comment: assimp довольно проблематично собирать c minGW - сам в своё время мучился с его сборкой в code blocks + minGW под windows - используйте visual studio (>= 2013)  и всё прекрасно соберётся

Comment: Я таки его собрал через Make в Win но это такой гемор...